# Wireless card won't turn on

Tags: 16.04, wireless, dell

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell Inspiron 1564. Suddenly, the wireless card is not turning on (network is disabled). However, the computer recognizes the wireless card (`lshw -C network`).

I tried starting it manually through terminal but it won't.

ok
i ran 
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
and here what i got :

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.